# CSS expanding width

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a highlighted code block expand on mouse-hover to make it easier to read the code (this part is dead easy). The code block is fixed-width and centered.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCj5a/)

```
.code-wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50em;
}

pre {
    background: #e5e5e5;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 200%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 500ms;
    width: 100%;
}

pre:hover {
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
}
```

The only potential issue is that if the screen width is less than 120em (60em x 200%) then the code is going to expand off-screen.

Are there any ways to do this ***without javascript*** that prevent the code block expanding beyond the edges of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following CSS code:

```
@media all and (min-width: 85em){
    pre:hover {
        left: -25%;
        width: 150%;
    }    
}

@media all and (min-width: 110em){
    pre:hover {
        left: -50%;
        width: 200%;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course. Very nice, very clean :) Just amended it to work off `em` so it scales nicely, and that's a perfect solution :) I'll accept it in 3 minutes when it lets me, thanks